# What's the difference between SharePoint and Exchange?

Tags: sharepoint-online, exchange

I am using SharePoint 2013. I just read something about SharePoint and **Exchange**. What is Exchange?

Thanks

Comment: Exchange runs email services, you know, like what Outlook connects to.

Answer (score 2):

**Exchange Server** Exchange Server, the Microsoft messaging and collaboration server, is software that runs on servers that enables you to send and receive electronic mail and other forms of interactive communication through computer networks. Designed to interoperate with a software client application such as Microsoft Outlook, Exchange Server also interoperates with Outlook Express and other e-mail client applications.

Read more here: https://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/windowsserversystem/exchange/evaluation/whatis.mspx

**SharePoint Server** while sharepoint is a place to store, orgnize, share the information, create web site and collaborate with your teams.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-SharePoint-97b915e6-651b-43b2-827d-fb25777f446f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 1):

An **Exchange** is the hosted version of Microsoft's messaging platform, Exchange Server.

Introduced as part of the Exchange Server 2010 release, Exchange Online gives companies a majority of the same benefits that on-premises Exchange deployments provide. By integrating with the Microsoft Outlook client, companies that use Exchange Online can make use of hosted email, calendars, and contacts, at a cost of  $5 (USD) per month, per end user. Microsoft Exchange Online is available as a standalone solution or as part of the Microsoft Office 365 collaboration suite.

Microsoft **SharePoint** is a browser-based collaboration and document management platform from Microsoft - Wikipedia. Microsoft's content management system. It allows groups to set up a centralized, password-protected space for document sharing.